# how to delete relevant resources when deleting a virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli

I am using `Azure CLI` version `2.34.1`. I ran following commands to create a resource group and then a virtual machine. Note that I used options to delete relevant resources when the VM is deleted.

```
az group create --name myTestRG --location eastus
az vm create --resource-group myTestRG --name myTestWindows11VM --image MicrosoftWindowsDesktop:windows-11:win11-21h2-pro:22000.493.220201 --admin-username someusername --os-disk-delete-option delete --nic-delete-option delete
```

Later I deleted the VM using following command.

```
az vm delete --name MyTestWin11VM --resource-group myTestRG -y
```

However, when I browse to the portal, the resource group still showing following resources that are relevant to the VM.
[image]

What I may be doing wrong? Is there anyway to delete all resources associated to VM when I delete the virtual machine itself?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE ITS A BUG:**

[image]

---

The way Azure works is to group resources in Resource Groups - its a mandatory field in all creation of services. Azure does this because many resources have dependencies, such as a VM with a NIC, VNet & NSG.

You can use this to your advantage and simply delete the Resource Group:

```
az group delete --name myTestRG
```

Azure will work out the dependency order, eg NSG, VNet, NIC, VM. You can read up on how it does the ordering: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/delete-resource-group?tabs=azure-cli

> What happens if I have multiple VMs in a Resource Group and I only want to delete one?

There's 3 new options  *--os-disk-delete-option, --data-disk-delete-option, --nic-delete-option* to support deleting VMs and dependencies:

```
az vm create \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myVM \
    --image UbuntuLTS \
    --public-ip-sku Standard \
    --nic-delete-option delete \
    --os-disk-delete-option delete \
    --admin-username azureuser \
    --generate-ssh-keys
```

Otherwise script the whole thing using Azure Resource Manager Templates (ARM Templates), or the new tool to generate ARM Templates called Bicep. It's worth continuing with raw CLI commands and delete dependencies in order. IF you get good with the CLI you end up with a library of commands that you can use with ARM templates.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If doing it through group is the way, what's the point of --os-disk-delete-option, --data-disk-delete-option, --nic-delete-option as described at this microsoft document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/delete?tabs=cli2?

Comment: I hadn't seen that feature. They're updating it all the time, probably added this recently to satisfy support requests.

Comment: So in the question I posted, I used some of these options during creation of VM script. But there are still some related resources left behind after the VM was deleted. That's what my question is about.

Comment: Sorry for missing that key info. I've gone through the FAQs and I can't see why deleting the NIC and NSG doesn't work?! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/delete?tabs=portal2  - you don't have the NIC and NSG locked? Is there an error when you run the `Azure vm delete` command?

Comment: no worries.  Nothing is locked and no errors when I run vm delete command. It seems to delete vm but not all resources

Comment: @whoami I can reproduce it, its a BUG. Depending on your country you'll need to call Microsoft and report this and because its a bug they're provide free support! Alternatively if via work you can raise a MS Support Case then your Tech Account Manager will action it.